# Required tag categories?

Tags: discussion

**Proposal**: create **two** required tag categories: **space** and **time**.
Every question must have a tag specifying the location **and** time period.

- If a question lacks a **time** tag, it is automatically tagged [whole-history](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whole-history).
- If a question lacks a **space** tag, it is automatically tagged [universe](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/universe).

Both [whole-history](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whole-history) and [universe](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/universe) are discouraged (although there are legitimate questions for which these tags may be appropriate - e.g., questions about [historiography](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historiography)).

**Rationale**:

**Pro**: for many questions the first comment (sometimes accompanied by a downvote and/or close vote) asks for a specific time period or region. Mandating these tags *may* force authors to at least consider restricting the scope.

**Contra**: this increases a barrier to entry for new users.

Comment: If you'd like the SE network programmers to change our software to automatically enforce something new and unique, you should probably ask on meta.se.

Comment: @T.E.D.: meta already has required tags - I think extending that should not be hard.

Comment: I like the idea of a general rule for time and space. I disagree with having "whole-history" and "universe" tags. "whole-history" should be assumed when there is no time tag. "universe" should be used, if at all, for questions about the history of thought about/study of the universe, not for the universe as a subject of history, since we can only do history of the Earth (and possibly the Moon, though there's not much that doesn't have to do with Earth).

Comment: I don't want to be the one to determine the time period tags. Every region in the world will need its own set of time tags. Or are you thinking to do it by century? But then question about the Tang Dynasty will include 4 different century tags?

Comment: @axsvl77: "tang dynasty" _is_ a time (and a space!) tag.

Comment: @sds So really what we require then is at least a setting tag, not necessarily separate time and space tags. That makes the rule a little too nuanced to enforce technically, don't you think? Why wouldn't we just make it a community rule and enforce the way we do any other rules on content (edits, votes, and comments)?